# Change the limit of digits in EditField based on the first input characters in Android?

Tags: android, editfield

I am working with a EditField in my application, to enter phone number to DIAL.

Now My query is,

```
1) if begins with 1, it should be only 10 max digits after the 1, 

2) if 011, up to 15 digits max, but no fewer than 8 after 011.
```

Please let me know, how this can be done in EditField.

Comment: check this link http://marakana.com/forums/android/learning_android_book/487.html for applying textwatcher on your edittext may be this will help you. Rest logic you have to write on your own

Answer (score 1):

add textWatcher to your edittext and change the max limit

Answer (score 0):

Here is answer to your solution. Its a very poor solution just a hint type but you can change code as according to you

```
final int LIMIT_FIRST = 10;
        final int LIMIT_SECOND = 15;
        final EditText et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edittext);
        et.setSingleLine();
        et.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                String stringValue = s.toString().trim();
                int stringLength = stringValue.length();
                if(stringLength == 0){
                    InputFilter[] FilterArray = new InputFilter[1];
                    FilterArray[0] = new InputFilter.LengthFilter(1000);
                    et.setFilters(FilterArray);
                }else if(stringLength == 1){
                    if(stringValue.equalsIgnoreCase("1")){
                        InputFilter[] FilterArray = new InputFilter[1];
                        FilterArray[0] = new InputFilter.LengthFilter(LIMIT_FIRST);
                        et.setFilters(FilterArray);
                    }
                }else if(stringLength == 3){
                    if(stringValue.equalsIgnoreCase("011")){
                        InputFilter[] FilterArray = new InputFilter[1];
                        FilterArray[0] = new InputFilter.LengthFilter(LIMIT_SECOND);
                        et.setFilters(FilterArray);
                    }
                }
                System.out.println(s);
            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                    int after) {
                System.out.println(s);
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                System.out.println(s);
            }
        });
```

Let me know if this helps you

Comment: Wellcome my friend if you need any more help you know where to find me :)